# Как вывести самую длинную общую подстроку?

Tags: javascript

Есть код, печатающий на консоль самую длинную общую подстроку всех переданных строк. При существовании нескольких решений — должно печататься одно любое. К примеру есть строка:`BBBAKPPP PPPNNNABBB MMMHHHZZZABBB` и должно печататься `BBB`, а печатается `A`.

```js
console.log("\n" + (function (str_arr) {
    for (var len = str_arr[2].length; len >= 1; --len) {
        for (var i = 0; i <= str_arr[2].length - len; ++i) {
            for (var j = 3; str_arr[j].indexOf(str_arr[2].substr(i, len)) !== -1;) {
                if (++j === str_arr.length) {
                    return str_arr[2].substr(i, len);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
})(process.argv));
```

Comment: эм, так ведь BBB это **НЕ ОБЩАЯ** подстрока, три подряд есть только в одной строке

Comment: @Grundy, простите, ошибся. Исправил

Comment: Проблема не воспроизвелась, для твоего примера, функция вывела `BBB`. Ты уверен, что проверяешь результат для верных входных данных?

Comment: Покажи как ты это все запускаешь

Comment: А что по твоему она должна выводить? :-)

Comment: @Grundy, да... Простите, туплю

Comment: То есть получается ошибки нет?

Comment: @Grundy, если строка состоит из 1 подстроки, то не выводит ее

Comment: Добавь пример входа, ожидаемого вывода и того, который выводится на самом деле

Comment: Вход: ABCDFKGJDS 
Выход:  ABCDFKGJDS
Результат :

Comment: просто добавь проверку на количество переданных строк, если передали одну - то ее и возвращать